# pdf_multivariate_gauss() function in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, ipython

Which are the necessary modules for execution of the function pdf_multivariate_gauss() in IPython?

I try to execute the below code but i get errors like "Import Error" and "Name Error".

***Code:***

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.mlab import bivariate_normal
import parzen_window_est
import pdf_multivariate_gauss   ######## ImportError ########
import operator


from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

##############################################
### Predicted bivariate Gaussian densities ###
##############################################


mu_vec = np.array([0,0])
cov_mat = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
x_2Dgauss = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu_vec, cov_mat, 10000)
# generate a range of 400 window widths between 0 < h < 1
h_range = np.linspace(0.001, 1, 400)

# calculate the actual density at the center [0, 0]
mu = np.array([[0],[0]])
cov = np.eye(2)
actual_pdf_val = pdf_multivariate_gauss.pdf_multivariate_gauss(np.array([[0],[0]]), mu, cov) 
######## NameError #########

# get a list of the differnces (|estimate-actual|) for different window widths
parzen_estimates = [np.abs(parzen_window_est.parzen_window_est(x_2Dgauss, h=1, center=[0, 0])) for i in h_range]

# get the window width for which |estimate-actual| is closest to 0
min_index, min_value = min(enumerate(parzen_estimates), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

[IPython output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqWUp.png)

Comment: I think you are confused with `pdf_multivariate_gaus` there no such module in python (as far as i know atleast). I could suggest you look into `scipy.stats`. 
May be you took the example[ form this ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101977/trying-to-plot-multivariate-gaussian-dist-in-a-3d-plot-matplotlib-returns-an-em) ? The function is defined in the text and you could try using it, if it gives results as you wish.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In scipy.stats i found the "multivariate_normal" not the "pdf_multivariate_gauss" and as i tested in your link(solution) the relative function works fine.Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no such thing as pdf_multivariate_gauss (as pointed out already). There is a python implementation of this in `scipy`, however: [scipy.stats.multivariate_normal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html)

One would use it like this:

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
mvn = multivariate_normal(mu,cov) #create a multivariate Gaussian object with specified mean and covariance matrix
p = mvn.pdf(x) #evaluate the probability density at x
```